# Using a multi-level drop down menu in a select operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am attempting to create a HTML form that needs to be able to accept 160 possible values for a given field, this will need to be done over and over again so I want to make it as simple as possible to find the value that I need.  Everything in my list can be grouped into sub categories, so I am imagining a multi-level drop down menu type approach [like here](http://spicebrains.com/multi-level-drop-down-menu/). I have seen a plethora of how-tos and sites informing me on how to do similar things where I simply make an unordered list of unordered lists i.e.:

```
<ul class="mlddm">
  <li><a href="#">Entity Provider</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">DBA</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Entity Type</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Individual Provider</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Name</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Full Name</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Prefix</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">First Name</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Middle Name</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Last Name</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Suffix</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Professional Suffix</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Birth Date</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Full Birth Date</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Day Of Birth</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Month Of Birth</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Year Of Birth</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Education</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Institution</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">City</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">State</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Country</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Start Date</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">End Date</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Graduation Date</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Degree</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and then apply some CSS and JS magic to the HTML to accomplish this.

This would be fine if I was using a menu to link me to another page, but I need to take a string value from what was selected and use it in a form. The problem is that I am fairly new to HTML and do not know how to extract what is selected from the above list and place it into my form (probably the easiest solution to this problem).

Another approach I have seen to this would be to indent the select list using styles and groups to create kind of a tree style view like this:

```
<select name="select_projects" id="select_projects">
    <option value="">project.xml</option>
    <optgroup label="client1">
        <option value="">project2.xml</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="client2">
        <option value="">project5.xml</option>
        <option value="">project6.xml</option>
        <optgroup label="client2_a">
            <option value="" style="margin-left:23px;">project7.xml</option>
            <option value="" style="margin-left:23px;">project8.xml</option>
        </optgroup>
        <option value="">project3.xml</option>
        <option value="">project4.xml</option>
   </optgroup>
   <option value="">project0.xml</option>
   <option value="">project1.xml</option>
</select>
```

This would be a nice solution if I were presenting say 40 options at most but where I have 160 options this will be overwhelming and simply will not do.

The last solution might be to have drop downs that take from each other to limit the options in the next drop down [like here](http://www.prodiven.com/jcombo/?lang=en).
This is also less than ideal as it requires us to select information hat does not actually get saved, it is simply to narrow options.  I will take this option if all else fails but I am hoping that someone might be able to help me out.

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to post form data, correct? If so, why not use the `ul` menu and have your lowest-level items be checkboxes with values?

Comment: Not in english, but these dropdowns are pretty cool -> http://flyrute.no/

Comment: @DrydenLong That is an interesting solution but I think it might get messy as I will be trying to make each row of data dynamic (as the row above it is populated)

Comment: @adeneo YES! perfect! how do I do that?

Comment: I made that one from scratch, took a lot longer than you'd think, but I'm sure there are plugins that do the same ?

Comment: I've looked far and wide (well as far and wide as an afternoon allows) and the closest I have been able to find is this:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus
which from the examples appears to do what I want but when I get into implementation it seems like it just works for links again.

Comment: @DrydenLong I think I misunderstood your comment the frst time I read it.  That actually sounds like a great solution. Could by chance modify my ul list code to show me how to put checkboxes in?

Comment: Just replace the `<a>` tags with checkbox input fields and wrap it all in a `<form>` element.

Comment: The entire ordered list or just the final values get wrapped in the form element?

Comment: I think I don't understand this question. Are you just trying to make a multi-level dropdown? And you want to populate a form with the selected data? Populate in what sense? Grab the selected data and use it as values for a particular input field ?

Comment: I am attempting to take the data out of the select and save it into a database for use at a later time in another application.

Answer (score 1):

I've use [this jQuery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) on projects in the past and it has worked a treat. There are lots of different options for the configuration, and all of the html is easily stylable with your own CSS if you don't like the default look.

Comment: This looks like a great plugin, and I think I will probably use it.  I like the optgroup support (which seems to be the route I will be taking with this now that I have had the weekend to think it over) but it does not seem to do what I was asking for in the original question which is support multi-tiered-selects.  Thank you for the suggestion though.